# Ng-grid problems manipulating column defs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a unique scenario where I do not know my width right away and I need to calculate it before.  So, before I run the column defs I have

```
var arr = [];
var part ={field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', width: allReadyCalc};
arr.push(part); 

*All the correct other code in between
data: 'random',
columnDefs:arr
```

I am pretty new to ng-grid so I do not know the exact way of doing this.  I have 10 objects so I have also tried running a loop in `columnDefs` and that has not worked either.

Ps: this is in javascript and `var arr to arr.push` is in a for loop.  I really just need help finding the right way of pulling this off, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I did wrong, my calculated width was too small to see since I did it for ever character of my title which is around 5 and that was lower than my minWidth.  Hopefully this will help anyone in the future giving columnDefs: an array.

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach is to put your text in a span that is offscreen, then get width of the span and use to set width of whatever filed you need to know the width of.